# Too many arguments in method calls

Tags: design-patterns, builder-pattern

Lately I've been torn when trying writing classes regarding the number of parameters requested.

A very simple constructor example:

```
Burger(bun, meat, cheese, lettuce)
    this.bun = bun
    this.meat = meat
    ...
```

Vs

```
Burger(grocery)
    this.bun = grocery.bun
    this.meat = grocery.meat
    ...
```

Both ways are valid approaches. The first way shows exactly what's going into the burger, breaks down the arguments into more general classes so it makes for less coupling, and I think is generally easier to test because the object graph is simpler.

But the second way is a lot simpler, cleaner, and perhaps the burger can require a lot more ingredients, then the arguments in the first way can balloon immensely.

I'd like to know which way would be recommended in a situation like this? Go for the cleaner but more coupled code, or the more verbose way.

Answer (score 5):

passing 4+ parameters to any method or constructor is not a good idea or a good design.

I remember that Joshua Bloch ([Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)) recommend [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to this situation (Item 2)

> [Item 2](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2): Consider a builder when faced with many constructor parameters